# CollectionView Cells Not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to show images in a `UICollectionView`. The code below is responsible for showing the cell.

```
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    memes = appDelegate.memes
    collectionView?.reloadData()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    let space:CGFloat = 3.0
    let dimension = (view.frame.size.width - (2 * space)) / 3.0

    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = space
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = space
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: dimension, height: dimension)
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1.0, left: 1.0, bottom: 1.0, right: 1.0)
}
```

and

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MemeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MemeCollectionViewCell
    let meme = memes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    cell.memeImageView?.image = meme.meme
    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}
```

All I see is a blank view controller. When I click the screen, the details VC popups up (as it should). It seems like the information for the view is there but just isn't being rendered on the screen. What changes do I need to make in order to ensure the images show?

Comment: is your view controller the data source ? does your cellForItem ever get called ?

Comment: use if your memes.count > 0 collectionView?.reloadData()

Comment: @JoshHamet in this case the data source is an array in the app delegate, cell for item at gets called

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i can see when there is data to show, it isn't being shown. reloadData is being called... nothings being rendered

Comment: You say that your `dataSource` array resides in the `AppDelegate`. How and where are you setting the `AppDelegate` as the `dataSource` of your `collectionView`? In simplest words, where is this statement `collectionView.dataSource = ???`?

Comment: Check for the datasource and delegate and prefer to use a library like kingfisher or import SwiftGifOrigin for gif if images or memes are being downloaded from internet

Comment: @Adeel i get a reference to the app delegate, then set the array to a instance variable in the VC. (look at viewWillAppear for details). Just tried setting the dataSource by casting the array to a UICollectionViewDataSource...it threw an error.

Comment: Your `dataSource` should be where you have implemented `cellForItemAt:` method i.e. if it is implemented in the `ViewController` then your should be setting `collectionView.dataSource = self`. What I understand is that you are confusing the `dataSource` with the dataSource array.

Comment: @Adeel dataSource is set to self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out I didn't have the module name set in the collection view controller in storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Your collectionview delegates are not being called. 
you have to write

`collectionview.delegate = self
 collectionview.dataSource = self`

And if the delegates are being called, please check if meme.meme has and image.

Comment: just tried adding in those two lines of code...nothing changed

Comment: since your cell is nil add
     if cell == nil {
            collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MemeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
           
cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as? MemeCollectionViewCell
        }

Answer (score 0):

1) use default method to provide flowLayout to a collectionView

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: width/3, height: 100)
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{

        return  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{

        return 0
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{

        return 0
    }
```

2) make sure you had initialised in code before you reload your collectionViw

```
collectionview.delegate = self
 collectionview.dataSource = self
```

3) add breakpoints in `numberOfItemsInSection`after relaoding and check do your meme array really have value the you reload CollectionView and if yes , of course it will after this go to `CellforRowAt` and check do your memeImageView is getting value or not . print image view using breakpoint just for try

Comment: I printed a description of the cell image, it was nil. Which is strange because the table view that I use to show the same data is showing the data as it should. I just check the connection between the imagview in the custom cell for the collection view and the code....the ib outlet seems to be working just fine

Comment: data is not coming in cell this is why it was showing black screen as View has nothing to show you must check for your meme array in Appdelegate in two steps just check that value is really getting to array in appeal or not and secondly if yes before you are about to use your appeal array anywhere print its description like count.

Comment: I just check the data the cell image is being set to. it is non nil. the cell itself is non nil, just the cell.imageView?.image property is nil. any guess as to why that is?

Comment: are you trying to add a GIF there in ImageView rather Than a image ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, when I debugged the issue it was that collectionView is not getting height to be displayed and delegate method cellForItem was not even working. 
Solution:
I set me leading and trailing constraint to the parentView outside stackView.
My view hierarchy was parentView->stackView->collectionView.
Comment if you have any question.